# Installing Lubuntu on a MacMini Intel for future dual boot

Tags: lubuntu, macosx, refind, mac-mini

I have an 'old' mid-2007 MacMini that works great hardwarewise (Intel Core 2 Duo 2GHz + 2Gb RAM) but I'm stuck at MacOS 10.6.8 (SnowLeopard) and most of the usual apps on it won't upgrade past their 2012-2014 versions now. I've been using Lubuntu on a laptop and loving it needless to say... So, I thought I'd try to install it on my MacMini alongside MacOSX, as a dual boot at first and then eventually sometime in the future trash the MacOSX stuff altogether and stick to Lubuntu alone.

I used BootCamp directly on the Mini to create a new 40 Gb MSDOS-FAT partition on the internal drive alongside the one that has MacOSX. It appears in the Disk utility tool and is automatically mounted to appear on the desktop as "BOOTCAMP".

I used unetbootin on my Lubuntu laptop to create a Lubuntu bootable 32bit USB key and installed refind on the MacMini through the command-line script that was delivered with the zipped file I downloaded. I would like to try Lubuntu on the bootable USB key first on the Mini to see how it runs and then of course install it to the BOOTCAMP partition on the Mini.

When I plug the bootable Lubuntu USB key onto the Mini and restart it, without having to keep any particular key pressed, Refind launches and shows 2 items to boot from : MacOSX and the Penguin (but it is not the usual blue bird-like Lubuntu logo though). If I choose the Penguin to boot off of, it turns to a grey screen with the Penguin in a darker grey shade in the center of the screen, it stands still for a bit and then displays the following message :

Starting legacy loader using option 'USB'

The firmware refused to boot from selected volume. Note that external harddrives are not well-supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting.
Hit any key to continue

And then my keyboard is ignored while I could use it earlier during the Refind launch to select which OS to boot from (it is USB-plugged Microsoft keyboard). No pressed key will then have an effect on the Mini. I have to use the on/off button to turn the Mini off and restart it.

So my question is : how do I get Lubuntu to start on the bootable USB key through Refind on the Mini ?

Any ideas?

Comment: The following questions seem relevant: [Why doesn't the Ubuntu ISO burned to a CD or copied to a USB work on my Mac?](/q/165744/175814), [How do I create an Ubuntu live USB using a Mac?](/q/86/175814), and [How do I install Ubuntu onto a Mac Mini?](/q/301457/175814). Could you please try the answers that (still) appear applicable and report back? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the following:

- You do not need rEFInd to install or boot Linux on a Mac. You can use the Startup Manager.
- You can use the modern EFI boot method with most Linux installations on a Mac.
- Your model Mac should support the 64 bit versions of Lubuntu.
- The USB flash drive, create using the steps shown below, was successfully tested on a iMac (20 inch, Mid 2007).

Here are the steps to create the USB installer and launch Lubuntu.

1. Download the Lubuntu iso file named `lubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso` to your "Downloads" folder.
2. Insert a 2 GB or larger USB flash drive.
3. Enter the command `diskutil  list` to determine the identifier for your flash drive. Here, I will assume this is `disk1`.
4. From a Terminal application window, enter the following commands. If the identifier for your flash drive is not `disk1`, make the appropriate substitution for `rdisk1`.

   ```
   cd  ~/Downloads
   rm  -f  target  target.dmg
   hdiutil  convert  -format  UDRW  -o  target  lubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
   if  test  -e  target;  then  mv  -f  target  target.dmg;  fi
   sudo  dd  if=target.dmg  of=/dev/rdisk1  bs=1m
   ```
5. If you get the following message, select "Ignore".

[image: c2]

6. Restart you Mac. Immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager appears.
7. Select the icon labeled "EFI Boot", then select the arrow below the label. If there are more than two "EFI Boot" labels, choose either one.

> Note: In the past, I was able to replace steps 3 and 4 with the use of UNetbootin. In this case, I did not test to see if UNetbootin still works.

If you have any questions or want to know how to proceed further, let me know.